Python RegEx: match words in a string only if they are not preceded by a specific character
For example:
something foo somethingelse // matches: [something, foo, somethingelse]
something1 something.foo-somethingelse // matches: [something1, something, foo, somethingelse]

but not if preceded by '>'
something1 something>foo-.somethingelse // matches: [something1, something, somethingelse]

I did develop this regex:
(?(?<!>)(\w+)|\w+)
(? - if
 (?<! - is not preceded by (negative lookbehind)
  > - literal '>'
 )
 (\w+) - capture a group of 1 or more word characters
 | - else
 \w+ - match 1 or more word characters without capturing them
)

which worked in regex101 (words starting with > weren't included in group 1), but that's when I learned that conditional regex is either not a thing in Python, or it doesn't work like in Perl.
Also correct me please if that is not true.

Do you mean like this? \b(?<!>)\w+ See https://regex101.com/r/hk1h5x/1 Or \b(?<!>)(\w+)|\w+ if you want to match the words that are not preceded by >

@Thefourthbird well, that works for me, thanks! I guess the \b thing is what I didn't know and hence missed. Mind posting that as a solution?

You don't have to use a conditional, you can use your negative lookbehind assertion and start with a word boundary:
\b(?<!>)\w+

See a regex demo
If you want to use the capture group:
\b(?<!>)(\w+)|\w+

See another regex demo
